# is it possible to compare char from string with set of chars?

Tags: c#

during parsing string I want to make decision when to stop and go to get next portion from string. My main goal is to take 3 portions of string 26 or less chars length. My code seems to me a little weird

```
for (basis=i*26; basis<name.Length
                    && name[basis] != ' '
                    && name[basis] != '-'
                    && name[basis] != '('
                    && name[basis] != ')'
                    && name[basis] != ';'
                    && name[basis] != ','
                    && name[basis] != '.'
                    && name[basis] != '"';
            basis--) ;
```

Comment: Use regular expressions. Stop rolling your own implementations of things that are provided for you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to use a Set:

```
var excludes = new HashSet<Char> { ' ', '-', ... };
```

Then test if your character is in the set with

```
excludes.contains(someChar)
```

[Set docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.iset-1)

Comment: Incoming nitpick ;-) The readability of `new HashSet<Char>(new[]{ ' ', '-', ... });` can be improved by forgoing the temp array creation and just using the collection initializer syntax:  `new HashSet<char> { ' ', '-', ... };`

Comment: @elgonzo excellent! Class I took required Java (whose collection initializers just... suck...), so I tried to remember the C# shorthand but that was all I came up with. Glad to remember there’s a better one.